# How I can put the header image above the slider with index CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on one task assigned to me. The URL to the site on which I am working on is given.
http://business-deal.ca/baby/

If you look at the slider the complete picture look like that
[image]

But the part one the header image is not shown because of the slider.
I mark black circle around in the following image.
[image]

I want this to be above the slider so the is should be visible. 
How I can push the slider down the image.?
The css code is given that I am using.

```
.header_image{
   position: relative;
}
.Header_banner {
  position: relative;
}
.main-header > .container {
    position: relative;
}
.header-wrapper {
    background: #faf1f5;
    margin-bottom: -66px;  
}
```

I am doing good changes in this through inspect elements, all code is visible there.
Please help me in this case I will be very thankful 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

After hard work I solved the issue and now it is working. If any one want to learn from inspect element the I added the following peace of code

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
    z-index: 30;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thank to everyone.